# How to extract the end of an string after a certain character with regex/java?

Tags: java, regex

I to parse multiple lines of text that, for example, look like this:

```
{"Name":"pathology[876]", "cpu":"0.58","mem":"18.39", "vm":"1542.14"}
{"Name":"/opt/pathology/bin/pathology[876]", "cpu":"0.58","mem":"18.39", "vm":"1542.14"}
{"Name":"/usr/sbin/ofonod[760]", "cpu":"0.00","mem":"0.00", "vm":"0.00"}
{"Name":"/opt/networking/bin/network_manager[370]", "cpu":"0.20","mem":"53.43", "vm":"4225.69"}
{"Name":"/usr/bin/dmrouterd[913]", "cpu":"0.00","mem":"0.00", "vm":"0.00"}
```

I have to extract every process name, but some come alone and as well with their related path which I have to ignore, for example: `pathology[876]` is that same thing as `/opt/pathology/bin/pathology[876]`. I have to generalize this process to take the process name indifferently of the path. How could I take the desired string between the last `/` and the end of the string?

So far I have computed the following regex that treats paths like: `/opt/<anything>/bin/<anything>` extracting part after bin/, but there is a problem where the path is longer, for example `/opt/<anything>/bin/pat/pathology[876]` I get `pat/pathology[876]` while I would want only `pathology[876]`.

```
"(Name)":("\/opt\/(.*?)\/bin\/(.*?)"|"(.*?)")
```

Comment: This looks like JSON. do you want to iterate over each JSON record? 
Or do you want to treat them as a single entry like a string?

Comment: I want to treat them like a string, the idea is that this JSON structure was embedded in a longer message, but I only selected it to be more concise with my question.

Comment: @LiviuIosim Anything wrong with the answer I gave 10 minutes ago?

Comment: Can we assume that every entry will look like your excerpt? Something like alphanumerical string followed by a square bracket enclosed process number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my steps to create such regex are:

1. Thinking about which characters are (not) included in my target string? In this case all chars are allowed, but " and / are not allowed: `([^/\"]+)`
2. What is written before my target string? In this case an optional string like /.../.../ which always starts and ends with /. To catch all ../../../ we can write `([^"\/]+\/)*` and to catch the first / and make it optional we just extend it to `(\/([^"\/]+\/)*)?`
3. What is written after my target string? -> "

The final regex could be:

```
"Name":"(?:\/(?:[^"\/]+\/)*)?([^/\"]+)"
```

(Note the syntax `(?:X)` will group the expression X but will not be captured as a "result group")

I've tested and saved this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/WnSNNk/2

Comment: Albeit a little hard to decypher, this is much more performant than my answer so +1 :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for your +1. But I like your "simple" regex more. It is easier to understand. I just didn't saw it.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it for you:

```
[^\/"]+(?=", "cpu")
```

In English:

Per line, find everything that's not a forward slash nor double quote leading up to `", "cpu"`

https://regex101.com/r/u3rhUf/1/

Comment: I am sorry for being inactive yesterday, this works really well, thank you for your input.